# Why SVG rotation was not centered?

Tags: css, svg, rotation, css-transforms

I have a simple SVG image. There is a circle inside which I would like to rotate `90` degrees. But as you can see in JSFiddle example center of the rotation is not in the middle. What am I doing wrong?

```css
svg {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.circle1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke: #b5b5b5;
}

.circle2 {
    fill: #aaa;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    stroke-width: 15px;
    stroke: #71c7ff;
}
```

```html
<svg height="600" width="600">
    <circle class="circle1" cx="300" cy="300" r="200"></circle>
    <circle class="circle2" cx="300" cy="300" r="200"></circle>
</svg>
```

Here is JSFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/oxt681gr/1/

Comment: transform-origin: center; ?

Comment: and maybe transform-box: fill-box;

Comment: But center it should be default value for rotate.

Comment: The [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#UAStyleSheet) disagrees.

Comment: Its too complicated. But for my purpose rotate of top svg element works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the origin of a transform should be `0px 0px`, but now we have wrong info on MDN:

> *By default, the origin of a transform is center.*
>
> [Source-link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

It is wrong. But in the case if it would be in center of your circle you would not able to see the result of your rotation because you will rotate the circle in his center.

You can change the rotation center with CSS property **[`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)** or with SVG [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) attribute. In SVG `transform` attribute we have the default also on `0px 0px`. To rotate SVG (without CSS) use `transform="rotate(deg, cx, cy)"`, where deg is the degree you want to rotate and `(cx, cy)` define the center of rotation.

In my solution you can change it interactive with CSS and JS:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input'),
    circle2 = document.querySelector('.circle2'),
    output = document.querySelector('span');

input.onchange = function(e)
{
    var newTransformOrigin = e.target.value;
    output.innerHTML = newTransformOrigin + 'px' + ' ' + newTransformOrigin + 'px';
    circle2.style.transformOrigin = output.innerHTML;
};
```

```css
svg {background-color:#ddd}
.circle1 {fill: none; stroke-width: 20px; stroke: #b5b5b5}
.circle2
{
    fill: #aaa;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    stroke-width: 15px;
    stroke: #71c7ff;
}
```

```html
<p>Change transform-origin <input type="range" min="0" max="600" value="0" step="50">
 <span>0px 0px</span></p>
<svg height="600" width="600">
    <circle class="circle1" cx="300" cy="300" r="200"></circle>
    <circle class="circle2" cx="300" cy="300" r="200"></circle>
</svg>
```

Please change to full page to see the example.

Comment: Your first two sentences are incorrect. There's no bug, that's what the SVG specification mandates. See https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#UAStyleSheet

Comment: @RobertLongson, okey, I am wrong. I will change it now. It was because of wrong info on MDN: *By default, the origin of a transform is center.* Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: MDN is correct for HTML, it's not right for SVG though. As SVG is less than 1% of the web by volume covering the 99% case may be good enough for MDN.

Comment: Thank you. Really nice explanation.

Comment: If somebody want support for IE, then he has to change my `onchange` function to `var tv = e.target.value;circle2.setAttribute('transform', 'translate('+tv+','+tv+')rotate(-20)translate(-'+tv+',-'+tv+')');` because IE has a bug – IE supports the transform attribute in SVG even though it doesn't recognize the CSS style.